# How to subset dataframe by last characters of a string in R

Tags: string, r, dataframe, subset

R-user,

I have this dataframe:

```
head(Niger_Meteo_98.11)
  X.ID_punto    MM.GG.AA T2m_max  
1          1    01/01/98 303.235 
2          2    01/01/99 303.356 
3          3    01/01/00 303.477 
4          4    01/01/01 303.604 
5          5    01/01/02 303.759 
6          6    01/01/03 303.915
```

and I need to get only values from year 2002.
So, I should select, on column `MM.GG.AA`, those rows that end with "`/02`". 
I didn't find anything online...any hints?
Thanks!

Comment: If your column `MM.GG.AA` is a date, i would format it as such with `as.Date`.  Then subset without regexes using the `format` function.

Comment: Hi Justin, I'm going to exploit your comment. I have to make a cicle for every dates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use standard subsetting with `grep`, like this:

```
x <- read.table(text="  X.ID_punto    MM.GG.AA T2m_max  
1          1    01/01/98 303.235 
2          2    01/01/99 303.356 
3          3    01/01/00 303.477 
4          4    01/01/01 303.604 
5          5    01/01/02 303.759 
6          6    01/01/03 303.915", header=TRUE)

x[grep("/02$", x$MM.GG.AA), ]

  X.ID_punto MM.GG.AA T2m_max
5          5 01/01/02 303.759
```

The `grep` regular expression `/02$` searches for string that end in `/02`, since the `$` indicates the end of the string.

Comment: great Andrie! Where did you get the info of this expression:
"/02$ searches for string that end in /02"
What about looking to the start of the string?

Comment: The function `grep` takes a regular expression a input.  Read the help for `?regexp` or `?grep` for more info.